# How would I automatically adjust the width of the dropdown content to match the width of the <p> element?

Tags: css, html

Basically, I have two `<p>` elements. When you hover over one `<p>` element, the dropdown content appears. The problem is, I want the dropdown *content* (the dropdown itself)'s width to **match** the width of the `<p>` element. [These images should probably describe what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmtiI.jpg). The red line I drew on the first image is what I would like to "cut off" or resize so it fits perfectly under the text.

Here is the code:

```css
#dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#dropdown p {
  color: #262261;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

#dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px auto auto auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  background-color: #262261;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-dropdown-container {
  width: 400px;
}

#dropdown-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 2;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#dropdown-link:link {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="applications">
  <div class="nav-dropdown-container">
    <div id="dropdown">
      <p>APPLICATIONS</p>
      <div id="dropdown-content">
        <center>
          <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="pages/nami.html">abc</a></p>
          <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="pages/jammr.html">def</a></p>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I really do not want to do this manually, I want this done automatically. Please, let me know if this is possible. Again, it's hard for me to explain what I would like done so I did my best. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `left:0;right:0;` with the `positon:absolute` element and remove all the width definition. The `inline-block` will make the width fit the content:

[**And get rid of the center tag.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

```css
#dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#dropdown p {
  color: #262261;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

#dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px auto auto;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  background-color: #262261;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

#dropdown-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 2;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#dropdown-link:link {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <p>APPLICATIONS</p>
  <div id="dropdown-content">
    <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="pages/nami.html">abc</a></p>
    <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="pages/jammr.html">def</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="dropdown">
  <p>extention</p>
  <div id="dropdown-content">
    <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="pages/nami.html">abc</a></p>
    <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="pages/jammr.html">def</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```